# "Volume" gives inconsistent results measuring the volume of a polyhedron

Tags: regions, polyhedra, volume, delaunaymesh

I use `DelaunayMesh` on a set of points and it constructs a polyhedron for me. And I want to get the volume of the polyhedron. If I do the following, it gives me a wrong value:

```
poly = DelaunayMesh[{{-13.745107953440002`, -1.2045192886102836`, 
     3.425826740210376`}, {-13.745107953439998`, 
     1.2045192886102876`, -3.4258267402103737`}, \
{-7.915608891747409`, -11.301866509683288`, 
     3.425698093441014`}, {-8.98831851917313`, -5.1894081166067085`, \
-8.674419697007096`}, {-5.829565822910857`, -12.506244037017224`, \
-3.4255600751795527`}, {-8.988318519173133`, 5.1894081166067085`, 
     8.674419697007096`}, {-7.915608891747411`, 
     11.301866509683288`, -3.4256980934410137`}, {-5.829565822910858`,
      12.506244037017224`, 
     3.425560075179553`}, {3.7168935781462386`*^-16, \
-10.37922335133299`, 
     8.674273670371923`}, {6.163261029072389`*^-16, \
-3.5583604142208735`*^-16, 
     12.397131948686622`}, {6.163261029072389`*^-16, 
     3.5583604142208735`*^-16, -12.397131948686622`}, \
{1.3972694572191914`*^-15, 
     10.379223351332993`, -8.674273670371923`}, {5.829565822910857`, \
-12.506244037017224`, -3.4255600751795527`}, {7.915608891747409`, \
-11.301866509683288`, 
     3.425698093441014`}, {8.98831851917313`, -5.1894081166067085`, \
-8.674419697007096`}, {5.829565822910858`, 12.506244037017224`, 
     3.425560075179553`}, {8.988318519173133`, 5.1894081166067085`, 
     8.674419697007096`}, {7.915608891747411`, 
     11.301866509683288`, -3.4256980934410137`}, \
{13.745107953440002`, -1.2045192886102836`, 
     3.425826740210376`}, {13.745107953439998`, 
     1.2045192886102876`, -3.4258267402103737`}}];

Volume[poly]
```

output:

[image]

However, if I first plot the constructed polyhedron like this:

[image]

and then copy the outputted shape into `volume` (apply the `volume` on the shape), it gives me a different result, which seems to be the right one:

[image]

Why these two results differ from each other and why the first method gives me the wrong result?

Answer (score 5):

`DelaunayMesh` generates multiple tetrahedra cells in 3D. Unfortunately, `Volume` and also `RandomPoint` only seem to consider one cell and not all of them.

Here's a simpler example than yours - a simplex with an extra interior point. The convex hull has the correct volume of 1/6, but the `DelaunayMesh` volume is wrong. And notice how the `RandomSample` only shows points from `DelaunayMesh` appearing in one of the tetrahedra.

```
points = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {1/2, 1/2, 1/2}};
delaunay = DelaunayMesh[points]
cvxhull = ConvexHullMesh[points]
Volume[delaunay] (* 0 wrong *)
Volume[cvxhull] (* 1/6 correct *)
ListPointPlot3D[{RandomPoint[cvxhull, 5000], 
  RandomPoint[delaunay, 5000]}, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

A workaround is to sum up all the volumes of the tetrahedra:

```
Total[Volume /@ MeshPrimitives[delaunay, 3]]
(* 1/6 *)
```

... and in your case for `poly` this gives:

```
Total[Volume /@ MeshPrimitives[poly, 3]]
(* 7075.9 *)
```

Why does copying the result work, as you described? I'm not sure, but looking at the `InputForm[poly]` and `InputForm[... the mesh object ...]` I can see some indices in the tetrahedra have been flipped around. This should be filed as a bug to Wolfram Support.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my confusion. I could report it to Wolfram and direct them to this post.